# Query help consolidating two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (same structure) from two different databases that I'd like to consolidate using a single query if possible.

I'm trying to retrieve all distinct serial numbers and their item name, and two category identifiers. The serial number is stored in 4 fields though. The other problem is the name and category field wont always be the same between the two tables (even though they should be - but that's another issue all together). So,  I want the query to return distinct SNs and the name and cat fields from the first table.

So I started with:

```
SELECT 
LEFT(NUMBR_1,4) + '-' + LEFT(NUMBR_2,4) + '-' + LEFT(NUMBR_3,3) + '-' + LEFT(NUMBR_4,5) AS SN
,DESCR
,TYP
,ATNUM
FROM DB1.dbo.table1
UNION
SELECT 
LEFT(NUMBR_1,4) + '-' + LEFT(NUMBR_2,4) + '-' + LEFT(NUMBR_3,3) + '-' + LEFT(NUMBR_4,5) AS SN
,DESCR
,TYP
,ATNUM
FROM DB2.dbo.table2
```

From there I'd manually complete the consolidation in Excel and feed that data into the necessary report. I was hoping to get the final result using just SQL, but doing so is outside of my skill set.

I wrapped the above query in another select to get distinct or group by SN -  which gets me the final consolidated list of SN. However, because those values themselves weren't something I could use to then query the other fields from the first table (at least that I could figure out), I wasn't sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the `create table` scripts and some dummy data with a desired output to illustrate your requirements and provide us something to work with?

Comment: @Jason Kimbel  Do you mean you could not access fields from an outer query from within the inner query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(NUMBR_1,4) + '-' + LEFT(NUMBR_2,4) + '-' + LEFT(NUMBR_3,3) + '-' + LEFT(NUMBR_4,5) AS SN,
    ,coalesce(t1.DESCR, t2.DESCR) DESCR,
    ,coalesce(t1.TYP, t2.TYP) TYP
    ,coalesce(t1.ATNUM, t2.ATNUM) ATNUM
FROM DB1.dbo.table1 t1
FULL JOIN DB2.dbo.table2 t2 ON
     t1.NUMBR_1 = t2.NUMBR_1 AND t1.NUMBR_2 = t2.NUMBR_2 AND t1.NUMBR_3 = t2.NUMBR_3 AND t1.NUMBR_4 = t2.NUMBR_4
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Just had to use coalesce for SN as well.

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer to Joel who beat me to it, though this will actually run.  Just swap out `@t1` and `@t2` for your table names.  `FULL JOIN`s return all records from both tables, and where there is no match, returns `NULL`s for one side and the unmatched values for the other:

```
declare @t1 table (numbr_1 int
                    ,numbr_2 int
                    ,numbr_3 int
                    ,numbr_4 int
                    ,descr nvarchar(50)
                    ,typ nvarchar(50)
                    ,atnum int
                    );

declare @t2 table (numbr_1 int
                    ,numbr_2 int
                    ,numbr_3 int
                    ,numbr_4 int
                    ,descr nvarchar(50)
                    ,typ nvarchar(50)
                    ,atnum int
                    );

insert into @t1 values
 (1,1,1,1,'d1','t1',1)
,(1,1,1,2,'d2','t1',1)
,(1,1,1,3,'d3','t2',2)
,(1,1,2,1,'d4','t2',3)
,(1,1,2,2,'d5','t2',4);

insert into @t2 values
 (1,1,1,1,'d6','t1',1)
,(1,1,1,2,'d7','t3',1)
,(1,2,1,3,'d8','t4',2)
,(1,2,2,1,'d9','t4',3)
,(1,2,2,2,'d5','t2',4);

select coalesce(left(t1.numbr_1,4) + '-' + left(t1.numbr_2,4) + '-' + left(t1.numbr_3,4) + '-' + left(t1.numbr_4,4)
                ,left(t2.numbr_1,4) + '-' + left(t2.numbr_2,4) + '-' + left(t2.numbr_3,4) + '-' + left(t2.numbr_4,4)
                ) as ID
        ,coalesce(t1.descr,t2.descr) as descr
        ,coalesce(t1.typ,t2.typ) as typ
        ,coalesce(t1.atnum,t2.atnum) as atnum
from @t1 t1
    full join @t2 t2
        on(t1.numbr_1 = t2.numbr_1
            and t1.numbr_2 = t2.numbr_2
            and t1.numbr_3 = t2.numbr_3
            and t1.numbr_4 = t2.numbr_4
            );
```